# If else expression in terminfo parameterized strings

Tags: terminal, c++14, terminfo, termcap

I am implementing a parser in C++ for parameterized strings(which are used for specifying some terminal capabilities for a terminal). Then I came across this on the man page of terminfo:

```
%? expr %t thenpart %e elsepart %;
   This forms an if-then-else.  The %e elsepart is optional.  Usually the %? expr part  pushes
   a value onto the stack, and %t pops it from the stack, testing if it is nonzero (true).  If
   it is zero (false), control passes to the %e (else) part.
```

So, my question is: 
As the man page says, that the `expr` part in the string can **usually** push values onto the stack, so what other things can be done in the `expr` part, that is, what other operations can be performed in the expr part except for pushing values on the stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short: "anything"

long: terminfo expressions use up to 9 parameters (for the obvious reason, digits **1-9** which in turn is the likely reason for **`sgr`** having 9 parameters).

In the given example,

> **`%?`** *expr* **`%t`** *thenpart* **`%e`** *elsepart* **`%;`**

think of it as a program

> **`%?`**
> *expr*
>  **`%t`**
> *thenpart*
> **`%e`**
> *elsepart*
> **`%;`**

that can enclose other *if-then-else* pieces.  However, the purpose of terminfo is to transform those parameters into a string to send to the terminal.  A literal character would be "output".  You could put literal characters as the *thenpart*, and those would be used for output.  Or you could compute some expression and *save* it temporarily, e.g., on the stack.  Doing that in both *thenpart* and *elsepart* lets you pop the stack after the *if-then-else* and either use it for output, or in some further expression.

xterm uses the feature in **`setf`**, **`setb`** and **`sgr`** (see link to ["xterm-basic"](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html#tic-xterm-basic)).

Comment: can these be nested? ie can expr/thenpart/elsepart contain more of these?

Comment: yes, for example [hp2382a](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-hp2382a) does that, as well as [wy350](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-wy350).